# Which type of event listeners are available for service workers

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, service-worker-events

Event listener function in service workers seems to be implemented from `EventTarget.addEventListener()`

```
    self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
       .....
});
```

This is the classic '**fetch type**' in a service worker

I am wondering if I can use any of those "**types**" inside a service worker.

From this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events , I can see several types of event listeners, such as 'click' or 'online' etc...

Is there any limitation of '**types**' that service worker accepts? 
If yes, how can I recognize those from the documentation?

I know that for most of them, service workers won't have any sense, but I would love to understand how this works internally.

Please note that by **type** I mean the first parameter of the event listener in a service worker such as 'install', 'fetch', 'active' etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may see the full list of supported events in the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#execution-context-events

They mostly deal with network and different sorts of messsages. As I see it, the only ones dealing with direct user interaction are the notification click/close events.